# Image within an image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, opencv

I've tried a snippet found here on stack overflow.
I would like to find an image inside another, doesn't matter if is rotated or resized.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import pathlib




os.chdir(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve())


image = cv2.imread('picture.png')
template = cv2.imread('penguin.png')

heat_map = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

h, w, _ = template.shape
y, x = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(heat_map), heat_map.shape)
cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 5)

cv2.imshow("pippo",cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The result is not as expected.

I got

[pippo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRQ0Z.png)

Thanks for an explanation.

Following the snippet i expected clearly that the penguin is inside the blue box

Comment: Please add edit your question and add the original `picture.png` and `penguin.png`. Please add the images, and not a screenshot of the images.

Answer (score 0):

The white cloud better matches the template than the penguin.

Since there are no brightness and contrast differences between the image and the template, we don't have to apply normalized correlation.

Selecting [cv2.TM_SQDIFF](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga3a7850640f1fe1f58fe91a2d7583695d) instead of `cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED` is going to give better matching for the above case.

---

Replace `heat_map = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)` with:

```
heat_map = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
```

---

The reason it works better is that the black part of the penguin is going to have much greater weight in the squared difference, compared to other methods.

---

Code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#os.chdir(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve())

image = cv2.imread('picture.png')
template = cv2.imread('penguin.png')

heat_map = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)

# Show the heat_map for testing:
cv2.imshow("heat_map", cv2.normalize(heat_map, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U))

h, w, _ = template.shape
y, x = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(heat_map), heat_map.shape)
cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 5)

cv2.imshow("pippo", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input image:
[image]

Input template:
[image]

Output:
[image]

---

Headmap with `cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED`:
[image]

Headmap with `cv2.TM_SQDIFF`:
[image]